# Is it correct to drop the repeating noun (except for the last one) in a list?

Tags: grammar, lists

I can't find the grammar rule about dropping a repeated noun in a list. I'm not sure what it's called and Search results weren't relevant. I'd like to try this construction myself if it's grammatically correct because I love how efficient it is.

For e.g.:

> Give them the blue, red, and green **crayons**.

versus

> Give them the blue crayon, red crayon, and green crayon.

Additional question: What's the best grammar book for someone who wants to dive deep into this topic? (I am an ESL person, but learned English as a teenager. I love English grammar!)

Comment: Perhaps look up _ellipsis_ on Wikipedia.

Comment: A caveat you must keep in mind is a massive propensity for misunderstanding. One, for example, may infer that you are discussing a blue, red, and green crayon in plural, that each crayon is tri-colored in blue, red, and green, or may infer that there isn't a singular blue crayon, a singular red crayon, and a singular green crayon, but plural blue crayons, plural red crayons, and plural green crayons. The only way I know neither of these two examples is true and what your actually mean is is from of your second example and how it, unlike your first example, makes your actual meaning clear.